# jni4net c# with java in jni4net java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, c#, jni4net

I built a very small and simple helloWorld program in java (has interface and in class has system.lang.out.println("hello world"))). I wrapped it with proxy gen. Now that I'm trying to attach it to c# (going by meCalc example) I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: Can't load java
>   class for dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958 from classLoader
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c387f44 --->
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIEnv.ExceptionTest()    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethodPtr(IJvmProxy obj, MethodId
>   methodIdNative, Value[] args)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(String par0)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.LoadClass(String name, ClassLoader
>   classLoader, JNIEnv env)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.LoadClass(String name, ClassLoader
>   classLoader, JNIEnv env)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterClass(RegistryRecord record,
>   ClassLoader classLoader, JNIEnv env)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.BindJvm(RegistryRecord record,
>   ClassLoader classLoader, JNIEnv env)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.BindJvm(RegistryRecord record, JNIEnv
>   env)    at net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterType(Type type,
>   Boolean bindJVM, JNIEnv env)    at
>   net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly,
>   Boolean bindJVM)    at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.RegisterAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly)    at netdt09120958.Program.Main(String[] args)

my c# code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var bridgeSetup = new BridgeSetup();
                bridgeSetup.AddAllJarsClassPath(".");
                Bridge.CreateJVM(bridgeSetup);
                Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(HelloWorld09120958).Assembly);

                IHelloWorld09120958 calc = new HelloWorld09120958();
                calc.SayHello();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

Why is that so? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it to work?

Comment: What's your Java package name? I think the error originated from `Bridge.RegisterAssembly` which refers to wrong package name/class name.

Comment: yes, you are correct, it does fail there.
my package name is: dt09120958
when i change it to package name i get: 'dt09120958' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: If you're sure Java package name & class name `dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958` is correctly placed at proper directory, check `JAVA_HOME` & classpath configuration. Use `java -version` command line to find out current Java version you're using. And what about `Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958).Assembly);`?

Comment: i have JAVA_HOME.
how do i check classpath?
java -version is  "1.8.0_144". 
using dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958 i get the same error.
correctly placed at proper directory - what do you mean? where should it be placed?

Comment: You can see that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). Are you already tried my suggestion to use package & class name: `Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958‌​).Assembly)`?

Comment: Are you already tried my suggestion to use package & class name: Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(dt09120958.HelloWorld09120958‌​‌​).Assembly) - yes i have, i get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154213/discussion-between-aura-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out java packages may not contain any uppercase letters.
the original JAR and the j4n.jar have to be in the same folder as the exe file. also when adding them to project make sure that in the properties they are marked as "copy always"
thankyou @Tetsuya Yamamoto

also i found this link which might help someone troubleshoot 
http://jni4net.com/troubleshoot.html